# Keep playing after finish Assassin's Creed: Brotherhood

Tags: assassins-creed-brotherhood

So I've just finished the main missions of the game, and it finished. But I still had secondary missions to complete, stores to restore, and a lot of stuff to do. Is there any way to keep playing in Rome, or at least recover the game before the last memory so I can do everything I want?

Comment: Pretty sure after it's all done you can just run around Rome as Ezio as you would normally. I did after finishing to finish up some other achievements. I got rid of the game, but I'll let someone else answer for sure with details.

Comment: Are you playing on PC? I've finished it today as well and got back in Roma just after the credits.

Comment: It took me about 80 minutes to watch the credits, wtf ?

Comment: That's a bit weird. It took me a lot of time, but not that much! :S

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just load your game from the main menu. You'll be back in Rome.

Comment: But when I tried it, it just loaded me the black screen with the credits. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hmm weird, works for me. Have you tried watching them to the end?

Comment: Yes. I've read the first line, and then waited, and that line appeared again. Maybe that was a bug. I don't know, but I'll try again. Then I say the result. :)

Comment: It's Working. Btw, the credits are really long lol. Tanks for the help anyway. :)